# What is the difference between the following two problems on combination:

Tags: combinations

**Problems:**
1. How many ways 6 balls can be distributed among three boxes?
2. How many equations of the form  $ax^2+bx+c=0$ can be formed if the coefficients are determined by throwing an ordinary six faced die.

I have  confusion with the second problem to distinguish from the first problem.

*Here,*  in the problem 1. Since each ball can be put into any one of the three boxes. So, the total number of ways in which $6$ balls can be put into three boxes is $3^6.$

*and* for the problem 2.
Why we can't think as: out of six numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6) each be taken by one of the three coefficients $a,b,c$. So the total number of ways should be $3^6$.
  But the actual answer is $6^3$. Why? please

Answer (score 1):

For problem 2, you have 6 options for a, 6 for b, 6 for c, so $6^3$ is correct.

For problem 1, the question is whether the balls are distinguishable.

If so, then you have 3 options for ball 1, .., three for ball 6, so $3^6$ is correct.

If not, then you have to do https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose any number in $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ for the coefficient $a $ so there are 6 possible choices.

For coefficient $b$ you have 6 choices as well, so you have $6\cdot 6$ total up until now.

For coefficient  $c $ you have another 6 choices so $6\cdot 6\cdot 6 = 6^3$ total ways.